# Visual Studio Cordova StatusBar Plugin

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to use the StatusBar Plugin in VS2013.  I have added it in the config.xml file.  When trying to access StatusBar.Hide() in my index.js code, StatusBar is not defined.  I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Having the same problem, and I am calling it in onDeviceReady. I noticed it did not add or have the StatusBar.d.ts file so I added that manually, and now its weird it will code complete StatusBar but when I build still complains it can't find that name.

Comment: ah needed to use window.StatusBar seems to work now

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are calling Status.Hide() after deviceready event is fired.

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    Status.Hide();
}